# Is this possible to load parquet file from aws s3 to the dynamodb through Glue?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, etl, aws-glue, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a solution to read the parquet file from s3 folder and dump to the dynamodb using Glue after doing couple of transformation .

```
ETL Process
s3-folder/parquet_file --> Glue_Transformation --> Dynamodb
```

Please let me know what would be the best solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved via AWS Glue.You can follow below approach :

1. Read from S3 parquet

`dyf_parq = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://s3-glue/testing-parquet"], "recurse"=True}, format = "parquet")`

2. then do your transformations
3. Once you are done you can write to dynamodb as shown below :

   ```
   glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
        frame=dyf,
        connection_type="dynamodb",
        connection_options={
            "dynamodb.output.tableName": "test_sink",
            "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
        }
    )
   ```

To know more about dynamodb as sink refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb) doc.

Comment: what versión of glue use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is completely possible to load a file from S3 to DynamoDB, Before starting this process make sure that you had:

1. Placed the file in the S3 bucket in a specific folder you like to.
2. Create a table in the DynamoDB, Choose the Primary key and sort key correctly while creating the DynamoDB Table.

Once the above steps are done.

The majority of the work is done in the Glue itself.

1. Create a crawler in the Glue and name the database, while creating the crawler and run that crawler after creating one. (This will create the schema for the data you are giving). If you have any doubt in creating the crawler go through this:
   [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-add-crawler.html#:~:text=To%20create%20a%20crawler%20that,Data%20Crawler%20%2C%20and%20choose%20Next](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-add-crawler.html#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20crawler%20that,Data%20Crawler%20%2C%20and%20choose%20Next).
2. Go to the left pane of AWS Glue under the ETL section click on the **jobs**.

You will be able to see something like this:
[AWS GLue Jobs Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iULBC.png)

Click on the create job, Once done, remove the Data Target - S3, because we want our data target to be the DynamoDB.

3. Now click on the data source - S3 Bucket and modify the changes like add the S3 file location and apply the transform settings based on your need.
   [Enter the data input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9FT6.png)

Make sure, there are no red indications like this:
[Red indications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEfxN.png)

Now, the answer to your question comes here:
Go to the script, click on the edit script and add this function in the existing code.

```
glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
 frame=<name_of_the_Dataframe>,
 connection_type="dynamodb",
 connection_options={
     "dynamodb.output.tableName": "<DynamoDB_Table_Name>",
     "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
 }
```

)

Make sure you had changed the:

1. frame=<name_of_the_Dataframe>
2. "dynamodb.output.tableName": "<DynamoDB_Table_Name>"

DynamoDB_Table_Name - One you had created in the DynamoDB.
name_of_the_Dataframe - This will be generated automatically, check out the variable name in the first function.

Once all the above steps are done, click on the save and run the script, and refresh the DynamoDB table.
This is "how", you can load the data from the Amazon S3 service to DynamoDB.

Note: The column name/feature name should not init cap.