# Trigger AWS Lambda with input parameters using S3 event trigger from multiple file paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

*New to AWS Lambda Development*

My lambda is reading a parquet file path from S3 location to move the data into DynamoDB.

Have a use case where I will have to trigger the same Lambda function to read the new files uploaded in multiple S3 paths. I am not sure how can we pass the file path into the Lambda call. If I put it in example -

- Lambda1 Call 1 for reading parquet from file_path1 - new parquet uploaded in path
  file_path1 - /abc/abc1/abc_1.parquet
- Lambda1 Call 2 for reading parquet from file_path2 - new parquet uploaded in path
  file_path2 - /xyz/xyz1/xyz_1.parquet

I am not sure if I have to provision multiple lambdas or can use one single lambda to be called multiple time with different file paths

Comment: FYI [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67752077/is-this-possible-to-load-parquet-file-from-aws-s3-to-the-dynamodb-through-glue).

Comment: thanks but not using Glue for this purpose for now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a single Lambda function for this, there is no reason to provision multiple copies of the function. You can probably just setup a single trigger on the S3 bucket that triggers the Lambda function on any new files. The path of the new file will be in the `event` parameter that your Lambda function handler receives.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the naïve question. I am not sure how will we pass parameter in the lambda invoke through step Function

Comment: You didn't mention step functions in your question at all. If you are using step functions, where does that fit in with your S3 and Lambda function setup?

Comment: sure agreed. Here is the flow - S3 Trigger -> Lambda00 -> StepFunction (Invokes Lambda1) -> Read S3 Parquet -> push Data to Dynamo

Comment: Why do you need StepFunctions and two Lambda functions for this process? Why not just have the first Lambda function (the one invoked by S3) handle reading the file and pushing the data to DynamoDB? If you stick with using StepFunctions, then your Lambda00 needs to parse the parquet file location from the `event` it gets passed in from S3, and then pass that as an input parameter to StepFucntions when it calls `StartExecution` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html

Comment: Thanks. Still trying to argue on using Step Functions with the architecture team. They are thinking for expansion in the future. But think I can go ahead with your solution by parsing the file paths. Thanks again for that.